# Incorrect dialog style on old android versions

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-styles

I have so style for alert dialogs:

```
<style name="Theme.Paper" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- customize the color palette -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/Theme.Paper.AlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.Paper.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.Toolbar" parent="Theme.Paper">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.AlertDialogStyle" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.Title">
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.TextAppearanceMedium">
    <!-- Set text size and color of message here -->
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_54</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.TextAppearanceLarge">
    <!-- Set text size and color of title -->
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_87</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.AlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.Title</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.TextAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLarge">@style/Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.TextAppearanceLarge</item>

    <item name="android:buttonBarStyle">@style/Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.ButtonBar</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/Theme.Paper.FlatButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.FlatButton">
    <!-- Set background drawable and text size of the buttons here -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_dialog_button</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">36dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">36dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">36dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">4dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Paper.AlertDialog.ButtonBar">
    <!-- Define a background for the button bar and a divider between the buttons here -->
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:dividerPadding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|right</item>
</style>
```

It looks normal on Android 4.x, but on Android 2.x devices I get just white dialog window with buttons (all text is white with default sizes)

How I can fix it?
P.S. Please, help me! I cannot publish my app because of this only...

Comment: Use only one style file in values folder, delete other like in values-v11 and and v14.

Comment: But I need to use default style on new Android version. How to make it than?

Comment: Then apply proper parent to style. Search for different kinds of parent for each control like button or dialog. They should be from AppCompat.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. How old android version can get styles from value folder v11 and etc?

Comment: And whatever I do, style in dialog doesn't change on old devices... I try to override textColor in different places of my styles but it changes text only on new Android versions

Comment: Please, can you help me with it? Just some example with style for dialog for old devices where will be changed a text color...

Comment: try [This](http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/). but dont use holo themes, like Theme.Dialog instead of Theme.Holo.Dialog.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot go to this site, I think, this resource is unavailable in my country. Please, can you write me code or upload it everywhere where I can download it?